# Quick Z-Index Issue

Tags: css, z-index

It's quite early and so I'm probably missing something apparent here but I'd like to ask the community for some quick help. When you visit the [demo page](http://genesis.glbranding.com/wp-test/) and hover over the slider, you'll see that the next and previous buttons appear as they should. Though the images have a "fold" effect on the left & right side and I'm trying to figure out why they're not showing.

I've toyed around with the z-index but can't figure it out. May someone please help with what should be a quick fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please describe in a bit more detail how is this 'fold' effect supposed to behave? Do you mean the transition effect when images change from one to another? If this is the case, I believe you should modify this line fx: 'simpleFade' and put another effect name there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set overflow : hidden on your

```
<div class="pix_diapo diapostarted">
```

Since your folds are outside of the containing element, it hides it.
Just remove it, and it will work.